# $_post checkbox value isn`t set inside echo

Tags: php, html

Why i can`t receive if checkbox is checked or no if i am ussing echo. If needed i can add the other part of the code. Thanks alot

HTML code

```
                    <?php 
                    $k=1;
                    foreach($prods as $prd){
                        echo '<input type="text" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;" class="form-control" name="prodid" placeholder="name" value="'.$prd['id'].'">';
                        echo '<tr>

                        <td class="movable">
                            <img src=".//assets/img/images_19.png">
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="prod_selected'.$prd['id'].'" value="checked">
                        </td>';
```

PHP code:Here is the new product php , here i also try to delete a product, by checking it`s checkbox and hiting the button delete.

```
<?php 
require_once "../assets/class/database.class.php";

require_once "../assets/class/category.database.class.php";
require_once "../assets/class/picture.database.class.php";
require_once "../assets/class/manufacturer.database.class.php";
require_once "../assets/class/tag.database.class.php";


require_once "../assets/class/product.database.class.php";
require_once "../assets/class/product_category.database.class.php";
require_once "../assets/class/product_picture.database.class.php";
require_once "../assets/class/product_description.database.class.php";
require_once "../assets/class/product_tag.database.class.php";
require_once "../assets/class/product_related.database.class.php";

require_once "../assets/class/functions.php";

var_dump($_POST['test']);
var_dump($_POST['test']);
if ($_POST['submit']=="add") {
    $nameid=rand(10,500);
    $product->_addNewProduct("Newproduct".$nameid);
    $pid=$product->_getid("Newproduct".$nameid);
    $url="http://dev.codemyworld.com/sven/product?id=".$pid[0];
    header('Location:'.$url);
    }

    $check='prod_selected'.$_POST['prodid'];

if (($_POST['submit']=="delete")&&(isset($_POST['prod_selected']))){
    $product->_removeProd($_POST['prodid']);

}
var_dump($check);
var_dump($_POST['$check']);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$check='prod_selected'.$_POST['prodid'];
```

to

```
$check=$_POST['prod_selected'.$_POST['prodid']];
```

Or, If you want `$check` to contain the key of $_POST array (as you do here), then change

```
var_dump($_POST['$check']);
```

To

```
var_dump($_POST[$check]);
```

---

Also, you HTML is not correct.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="prod_selected'.$prd['id'].'" value="checked">
```

should be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="prod_selected'.$prd['id'].'" checked="checked">
```

Comment: Still not working. I put value="checked" to try different ways. I still can`t get it working.

Comment: Have you read the answer ? You should have `checked="checked"`... You can always use `var_dump($_POST);` to see what you get from your form submit.

Comment: Be sure i looked on your answer and i modified, but it isn`t sending me his status to POST.

Comment: What you get in `$_POST` array ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your html for check
it should be checked = "checked" and not value="checked"

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) is some help.

Answer (score -1):

...this is wrong you have assigned a the value "checked" to this checkbox. if checked and submitted value will read checked

it should be...

on php side do this

$poduct = $_POST['prod_selected']; //this will give the value of the product_id...